# StartActivityforResult for child not get back the result?

Tags: android, android-emulator

HI,

I have tabhost with child activity , from that child Activity i going to start the new Activity not as child activity, for that i start activity using the method "startActivityForResult" but it doesn`t return the the result from new Activity to previous child of tab Activity.

i StartActivity as follows,

```
startActivityForResult((new Intent(tabchild.this,
                    NewInstanceActivity.class)),requestCode);

 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data) {
      if(resultCode==1){
               system.out.println("Activity started");
      }
      else{
          system.out.println("Activity not started");
      }
  }
```

in NewInstanceActivity.class, i return the result as follow,

```
Intent in = new Intent();
setResult(1, in);
```

but it doesn`t work.Anyone suggest some technique to solve this.

Thanks

Comment: `but it doesn't work.` If there is any problem then you must post some error log from `LogCat`

Comment: I presume that you are calling finish() after you have setResult()?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use putExtra() to get the return value you're looking for. Then you can refer to it with the name you gave it like "returnedData"

```
Intent intent= getIntent();
  String msg = intent.getStringExtra("sampleData");
  msg += ", This is my message";
  intent.putExtra("returnedData", msg);
  setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
  finish();
```

Comment: No you don't. If you only want to know the resultCode, extras aren't necessary

Comment: use getParent.SetResult(Intent,data);